# matlab: randomly permuting rows and columns of a 2-D array

Tags: python, matlab, random, permutation

I have a large matrix (approx. 80,000 X 60,000), and I basically want to scramble all the entries (that is, randomly permute both rows and columns independently).

I believe it'll work if I loop over the columns, and use randperm to randomly permute each column. (Or, I could equally well do rows.) Since this involves a loop with 60K iterations, I'm wondering if anyone can suggest a more efficient option?

I've also been working with numpy/scipy, so if you know of a good option in python, that would be great as well.

Thanks!
Susan

Thanks for all the thoughtful answers! Some more info: the rows of the matrix represent documents, and the data in each row is a vector of tf-idf weights for that document. Each column corresponds to one term in the vocabulary. I'm using pdist to calculate cosine similarities between all pairs of papers. And I want to generate a random set of papers to compare to.

I think that just permuting the columns will work, then, because each paper gets assigned a random set of term frequencies. (Permuting the rows just means reordering the papers.) As Jonathan pointed out, this has the advantage of not making a new copy of the whole matrix, and it sounds like the other options all will.

Comment: Scrambling all the entries is not equivalent to scrambling rows and columns independently. *n!m!* is not *(nm)!*. It means that you don't get all cases by scrambling rows and columns. Does it matters to you? Which option do you prefer?

Answer (score 4):

<del>You should be able to `reshape` the matrix to a 1 × 4800000000 "array", `randperm` it, and finally `reshape` it back to a 80000 × 60000 matrix.</del>

<del>This will require copying the 4.8 billion entries 3 times at worst. This might not be efficient.</del>

**EDIT**: Actually Matlab automatically uses linear indexing, so the first `reshape` is not needed. Just

```
reshape(x(randperm(4800000000), 80000, 60000))
```

is enough (thus reducing 1 unnecessary potential copying).

---

Note that, this assumes you have a dense matrix. If you have a sparse matrix, you could extract the values, and then randomly reassign indices to them. If there are N nonzero entries, then only 8N copying are needed at worst (3 numbers are required to describe one entry).

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better to do this:

```
import numpy as np

flat = matrix.ravel()
np.random.shuffle(flat)
```

You are basically flattening the matrix to a list, shuffling the list, and then re-constructing a matrix out of the list.

Comment: I'd have given you a +1 if you'd suggested `numpy.random.shuffle` and skipped the `tolist`. Copying the entire matrix into a list is extremely expensive when it contains 4.8e+09 elements.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Numpy with matrices enough to know all of this. I use Sage when I *really* have to.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of correcting the example. Note that it works with `np.array`, but not `np.matrix` (at least not on my box).

Comment: @larsmans: Thanks. I didn't have Numpy on the machine I wrote the example on, so I wasn't sure if it would even run.

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions above are great, and will work, but I believe both will involve making a completely new copy of the entire matrix in memory while doing the work. Since this is a huge matrix, that's pretty painful. In the case of the MATLAB solution, I think you'll be possibly creating two extra temporary copies, depending on how reshape works internally. I think you were on the right track by operating on columns, but the problem is that it will only scramble along columns. However, I believe if you do randperm along rows after that, you'll end up with a fully permuted matrix. This way you'll only be creating temporary variables that are, at worst, 80,000 by 1. Yes, that's two loops with 60,000 and 80,000 iterations each, but internally that's going to have to happen regardless. The algorithm is going to have to visit each memory location at least twice. You could probably do a more efficient algorithm by writing a C MEX function that operates completely in place, but I assume you'd rather not do that.